# Looking into row for data match MySQLi

Tags: php, mysqli

```
   <?php
include_once("php_includes/check_login_status.php");
if($user_ok != true){
       header("location: login.php");
    exit();
    }
?>

 <?php  
        $result = mysqli_query($db_conx, "SELECT active FROM profilepage WHERE username='$u'") or die(mysqli_error($db_conx));
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) or die ("$u not found"); 
        $a_check = $row['active'];

        if ($u == $log_username && $user_ok == true && $a_check = 1){
            echo include_once("videofeedform.php"); }
            else ($user_ok != true && $a_check = 1 or $user_ok = true && $a_check = 1);
             { echo "viewers should only see this"; }
                exit();

        if($u == $log_username && $user_ok == true && $a_check = 0 or $u != $log_username && $user_ok == true && $a_check = 0 or $u != $log_username && $user_ok != true && $a_check = 0)
        ($a_check = 0); {
            echo ' Video is going to be added here'; }
            exit();

        ?>
```

ok so basically I am trying to make a module work only if it has been activated to work by the user. Only the owner of the pages sees what they is mean to and the viewer only sees what they are meant to so that part works perfect however i need to tell the script to do these IF's only if the data inside the row match 1 and if they do not match 1 (e.g 0) then they do something else. I believe the current search is only looking for a number of rows called active what is owned by the user and if it is then do...... I was wondering how I would make the query look inside the row to find the data it needs to execute as it just seems like it is just executing when it finds 1 row that matches

Comment: `=` is not equal! Should be `==`

Comment: ok so it should be '$a_check == 1' in the 'if'

Comment: shouldn't it be `$row == 1` during the `if's`?

Comment: you're comment doesn't help what so ever. I hav tried all possibilities with == and nothing happens at all

Comment: You have more error in your code... for example: don`t need `echo` for  `include_once("videofeedform.php");` ... change your if condition in: `if (condition) { ... } else { ... }` ... your second if condition is very wrong .... and so on... I suggest you to learn a little more about the php language ... Here is a good start: [www.phptherightway.com](http://www.phptherightway.com/)

Comment: you should be doing that filtering in the query. `WHERE .... active=1` instead. Don't force mysql/php send data across the wire when you're just going to throw it away

Comment: Cheers for the help but I am unable to solve the problem. All suggestions that have been given just mess up with what people see what and basically everyone just see's "Only viewers should see this"

Comment: learn basic of programming and then post here if you have face any problem

Comment: I have watched many of videos and read 1 or 2 books. I am new and I know I am but you can't ask a book or a video questions on learning can you! I was posting to help me get a better grasp on PHP. If I can't post for help here regardless my skill level on programming then I am sorry for miss understanding this website as I thought it was also for educational purposes as well as general enquirers on stuff. If someone doesn't have the time or funding for college then how is someone meant to ask questions? I thought Stackoverflow was about a community with help and knowledge.

Comment: I believe if I ever am able to master php or even get slightly good at it you can guarantee I will be helping out other fellow noobies ON THIS SITE when i come across them as we all need to start somewhere and we all need to go wrong and be corrected. The above code is something I was trying. Designing my own after like 4-5 days of learning php (from books, videos and experimenting) so yes it will be wrong but at least I am already trying to come up with modules of my own regardless of the help I get making it work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay there is a decent amount wrong with this script.

you never show us what $log_username or $user_ok so I cannot help to evaluate whether those contain the correct values in your script.  We'll just assume they do.

---

You must brush up on your usage of [Comparison Operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) in php.:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

throughout the conditionals(if, elseif, etc..) in your script you have things like:

```
if ( $a_check = 1 )
```

but with a single '=' you are assigning the integer value 1 to the variable $a_check, this is basically the same thing as saying:

```
if (1)`
```

which evaluates to true in your if statement (any integer value other than 0 will always evaluate to true).

similarly the line

```
if ( $a_check = 2 )
```

is the same as

```
if (2)
```

and would also evaluate to true

as aldanux mentioned in his comment above, if you would like to compare if 2 variables are equal you should use ==.

```
if ( $var1 == $var2 )
```

if they are equal this will evaluate to true.

---

More issues with conditionals:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php

this block:

```
if ($u == $log_username && $user_ok == true && $a_check = 1){
    echo include_once("videofeedform.php"); }
    else ($user_ok != true && $a_check = 1 or $user_ok = true && $a_check = 1);
     { echo "viewers should only see this"; }
    exit();
```

should be more like:

```
if ($u == $log_username && $user_ok == true && $a_check == 1){
    echo include_once("videofeedform.php"); 
}

else if ($user_ok != true && $a_check == 1 or $user_ok == true && $a_check == 1)
{ 
    echo "viewers should only see this"; 
    exit(); //move exit inside the elseif block
}
```

1. fixed conditionals
2. use elseif since you want to evaluate another expression (e.g. $user_ok != true && $a_check == 1 or $user_ok == true && $a_check == 1),
3. remove semicolon from the end of your else statements
4. move exit() inside the elseif block (as you currently have the script would always exit on that line).

also an additional comment. the expression:

```
else if ($user_ok != true && $a_check == 1 or $user_ok == true && $a_check == 1)
```

is saying i don't care is $user_ok is true or false as long as $a_check equals one. This is  the same thing as doing:

```
else if ($a_check == 1)
```

though... now im thinking you just want to exit if your previous if statment false:

```
 if ($u == $log_username && $user_ok == true && $a_check == 1) //if this fails, exit
```

so your code there would actually look something more like:

```
if ($u == $log_username && $user_ok == true && $a_check == 1){
    echo include_once("videofeedform.php"); 
}

else{ //just remove the expression from here
    echo "viewers should only see this"; 
    exit(); //move exit inside the elseif block
}
```

---

these same issues discussed above exist with your last if statement.

Comment: First of all. Thank you ever so much for your time to post such an answer. Second of all thank you for pointing me in the direction to learn more about what I need to know (I am a beginner as you can obviously tell). Third of all thank you for the lessons in between the code. I am now going to study your post and the links you provided. Once again thank you ever so much sir.